# django - why is this custom middleware not working

Tags: django

I am building a website using django 1.10. I have written a middleware class to restrict the number of page views for users that are not logged in. I implemented this functionality into a separate application 'pagerestrict'

**settings.py [Relevant Entries]**

```
# Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',

        'django.contrib.sites',

        'pagerestrict.apps.PagerestrictConfig',
        # ...
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 

        'pagerestrict.middleware.CheckPageAccessMiddleware',    
    ]
```

**Middleware code (middleware.py):**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from decouple import config

class CheckPageAccessMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            current_page_url = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

            ignore_list = config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_IGNORES', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])

            #if not current_page_url or not any(current_page_url != url for url in ignore_list):
            if not current_page_url in ignore_list:
                # first things first ...
                if not has_attr(request, 'pages_visited'):
                    request.pages_visited = set()

                if not has_attr(request, 'page_count'):
                    request.page_count = 0

                if current_page_url not in request.pages_visited:
                    request.pages_visited.add(current_page_url)

                request.page_count += 1

                if request.page_count > config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_LIMIT'):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(config('PAGE_RESTRICT_REDIRECT_URL'))
```

I tested this by going to my homepage and refreshing the browser several times - the code never seemed to be triggered. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got this to work.  It was based on the [Middleware](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908120829/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/1721/middleware#t=2017090812082911872) topic on the now defunct Stack Overflow Documentation site. (Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/1721). Reference topic ID: 1721.)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from decouple import config

class CheckPageAccessMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, next_layer=None):
        """We allow next_layer to be None because old-style middlewares
        won't accept any argument.
        """
        self.get_response = next_layer

    def process_request(self, request):
        """Let's handle old-style request processing here, as usual."""
        # Do something with request
        # Probably return None
        # Or return an HttpResponse in some cases
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            current_page_url = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
            print ('Current page url: {0}'.format(current_page_url))

            root_url = '' # root url == ('')
            restrict_redirect_page = config('PAGE_RESTRICT_REDIRECT_URL')[1:]  # chop of leading '/'
            ignore_list = [root_url, restrict_redirect_page] + \
                config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_IGNORES', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])
            print('ignore list: %s' % ",".join([x for x in ignore_list]))

            #if not current_page_url or not any(current_page_url != url for url in ignore_list):
            if not current_page_url in ignore_list:
                # first things first ...
                if 'pages_visited' not in request.session:
                    request.session['pages_visited'] = ''

                if 'page_count' not in request.session:
                    request.session['page_count'] = 0

                pages_visited = [x.strip() for x in request.session['pages_visited'].split(',')]
                if current_page_url not in pages_visited:
                    pages_visited.append(current_page_url)
                    request.session['pages_visited'] = ",".join(x.strip() for x in pages_visited)

                request.session['page_count'] += 1

                print('Request page count: {0}'.format(request.session['page_count']))

                if request.session['page_count'] > config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_LIMIT', cast=int):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(config('PAGE_RESTRICT_REDIRECT_URL')) 

        return None


    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """Let's handle old-style response processing here, as usual."""
        # Do something with response, possibly using request.
        return response


    def __call__(self, request):
        """Handle new-style middleware here."""
        response = self.process_request(request)
        if response is None:
            # If process_request returned None, we must call the next middleware or
            # the view. Note that here, we are sure that self.get_response is not
            # None because this method is executed only in new-style middlewares.
            response = self.get_response(request)

        response = self.process_response(request, response)
        return response
```

Answer (score 15):

New-style middleware does not call `process_request` and `process_response` by default. This functionally has been replaced with `__call__` and the `get_response` function that is passed to `__init__`.

You need to call `process_request()` inside `__call__` and process the return value if it is not `None`. The easiest way to do this is to use the `MiddlewareMixin` provided by Django. This will define the necessary `__init__` and `__call__` methods, and `__call__` will call `process_request()` and `process_response()` if they are defined.

```py
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class CheckPageAccessMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            current_page_url = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

            ignore_list = config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_IGNORES', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])

            #if not current_page_url or not any(current_page_url != url for url in ignore_list):
            if not current_page_url in ignore_list:
                # first things first ...
                if not has_attr(request, 'pages_visited'):
                    request.pages_visited = set()

                if not has_attr(request, 'page_count'):
                    request.page_count = 0

                if current_page_url not in request.pages_visited:
                    request.pages_visited.add(current_page_url)

                request.page_count += 1

                if request.page_count > config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_LIMIT'):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(config('PAGE_RESTRICT_REDIRECT_URL'))
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The problem persists however - I can still refresh a page (say http://localhost:8000/foobar) more than **N** times, and the middleware doesn't seem to be getting fired. Placing print statements in the `process_request()` does not print anything to the console, browser or django logfile - so I'm flying completely in the dark.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I don't see anything obvious that could still be wrong. Did you restart the server? Is Django using the correct settings file?

Comment: Yes I restartd the server. Is there anyway to get the print statements in the middleware class to print to the console (or anywhere for that matter)? - at least, then I have a chance of figuring out what is going on. At the moment, I suspect it's not being called at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can change import like this:

```
try:
    from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
except ImportError:
    MiddlewareMixin = object
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here is an example to show how to update the middleware when migrating to
  `Django ver > 1.10`:
  [Upgrading pre-Django 1.10-style middleware](https://github.com/mozilla/addons-server/pull/9318/files)
- **If it does not work:**
  You should also temporarily remove all `default MIDDLEWARE class`,
  keeping only `your custom MIDDLEWARE` to make sure the previous
  layers(`default MIDDLEWARE`) did not break the flow:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = (
    # 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.MyMiddlewareClass',
)
```

- If you remove `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` then it works. That could be `ALLOWED_HOSTS` problem.

```py
- Replace
ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['localhost:8001']
- With
ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['localhost']
```

Answer (score -3):

New-style middleware does not call process_request and process_response by default. 
This functionally has been replaced with **call** and the get_response function that
 is passed to **init**.NYou need to call process_request() inside **call** and 
process the return value if it is not None. 
So you can write the code that you want to put into process_request() method to **call**() as below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from decouple import config

class CheckPageAccessMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, next_layer=None):
             self.get_response = next_layer

    def __call__(self, request):
         if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            current_page_url = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

            ignore_list = config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_IGNORES', cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')])

            #if not current_page_url or not any(current_page_url != url for url in ignore_list):
            if not current_page_url in ignore_list:
                # first things first ...
                if not has_attr(request, 'pages_visited'):
                    request.pages_visited = set()

                if not has_attr(request, 'page_count'):
                    request.page_count = 0

                if current_page_url not in request.pages_visited:
                    request.pages_visited.add(current_page_url)

                request.page_count += 1

                if request.page_count > config('PAGE_RESTRICT_PAGE_LIMIT'):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(config('PAGE_RESTRICT_REDIRECT_URL'))
```